# In Windows 7, if I play a full screen game, then all apps become "full screen" as well

Tags: windows-7, macos, boot-camp

In Windows 7, when I play a full screen game, then quit the game, all windows, such as those belonging to Firefox or Windows Explorer, become full screen as well. This means that they will expand to the full screen, as if the taskbar did not exist.

Anyone know how to fix this?

***EDIT (2011/12/01 @2PM EST): Some responses to the comments for this post:***

- When an app is in full screen made, the taskbar is still visible, so hitting the Windows key does indeed still bring up the Start Menu.
- These "full screen" windows are really resized to the full screen sized; they are not merely maximized. The taskbar covers the bottom part of the window, so for Firefox for instance, the status bar is covered by the taskbar at the bottom.
- The games I am playing are running as the same resolution as the screen (1920x1080). The games are also in that resolution, which is the native one.
- This happens for all full screen games, ranging from *Frozen Synapse* to *The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim* and everything in between.

I should also note that I have two LCD monitors side-by-side. The main window is on the right, which has the taskbar. This full screen problem doesn't exist on the left monitor since that monitor doesn't even have a taskbar, so windows are always full screen on that monitor. I now realize that having a second monitor might be related, or perhaps even the cause.

I'm also running Windows 7 in Boot Camp on a Mac, although I don't know if that's causing any problems. This also only started happening fairly recently, I think since the release of the latest OS X version, Mac OS X Lion, which was released in July 20, 2011. A new version of Boot Camp was released along with that, which just appears to drop support for old Windows OSes, but perhaps it installed new Mac drivers that are causing problems?

Comment: When in this full screen mode, does the Start Menu show up when you press the **Windows** key?

Comment: Are they resized to the full screen size, or are they maximised?  Are the games you are playing runing at the same resolution as the screen (assuming LCD)?

Comment: Is this one game or all games?

Comment: I posted my responses as an edit to the original post, above.